# Is there a Rust library with an UTF-16 string type? (intended for writing a Javascript interpreter)

Tags: string, rust, utf-16

For *most* programs, it's better to [use UTF-8 internally](http://utf8everywhere.org/) and, when necessary, convert to other encodings. But in my case, I want to write a Javascript interpreter, and it's much simpler to store only UTF-16 strings (or arrays of `u16`), because

1. I need to address 16-bits code units individually (this is a bad idea in general, but Javascript requires this). This means I need it to implement `Index<usize>`.
2. I need to store unpaired surrogates, that is, malformed UTF-16 strings (because of this, ECMAScript strings are technically defined as arrays of `u16`, that [*usually*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.16) represent UTF-16 strings). There is an encoding aptly named [WTF-8](https://simonsapin.github.io/wtf-8/) to store unpaired surrogates in UTF-8, but I don't want to use something like this.

I want to have the usual owned / borrowed types (like `String` / `str` and `CString` / `CStr`) with all or most usual methods. I don't want to roll my own string type (if I can avoid).

Also, my strings will always be immutable, behind an `Rc` and referred from a data structure containing weak pointers to all strings (implementing [string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning)). This might be relevant: perhaps it would be better to have `Rc<Utf16Str>` as the string type, where `Utf16Str` is the unsized string type (which can be defined as just `struct Utf16Str([u16])`). That would avoid following two pointers when accessing the string, but I don't know how to instantiate an `Rc` with an unsized type.

Given the above requirements, merely using rust-encoding is very inconvenient, because it treats all non-UTF-8 encodings [as vectors of `u8`](https://lifthrasiir.github.io/rust-encoding/encoding/types/trait.Encoding.html#method.encode).

Also, I'm not sure if [using the std library](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-stabilize-utf-16-encoding-in-std/2152) at all might help me here. I looked into `Utf16Units` and it's just an iterator, not a proper string type. (also, I know `OsString` doesn't help - I'm not on Windows, and it doesn't even implement `Index<usize>`)

Comment: Why don't you want to use WTF-8? AFAIK that's what Servo does.

Comment: Aren't Javascript strings in Servo actually owned by SpiderMonkey? In SpiderMonkey, strings are [arrays of char16_t](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference/JSString). My understanding is that Servo stores WTF-8 when the string is not owned by the Javascript engine, converting to UTF-16 when it is stored in a Javascript value (I want to write a Javascript *interpreter*, not a browser). See also [this article](https://blog.mozilla.org/research/2014/08/26/javascript-servos-only-garbage-collector/).

Comment: I think you're right, nevermind.

Answer (score 8):

Since there are multiple questions here I’ll try to respond separately:

---

I think the types you want are `[u16]` and `Vec<u16>`.

The default string types `str` and `String` are wrappers around `[u8]` and `Vec<u8>` (not technically true of `str` which is primitive, but close enough). The point of having separate types is to maintain the invariant that the underlying bytes are *well-formed in UTF-8*.

Similarly, you could have `Utf16Str` and `Utf16String` types wrapping around `[u16]` and `Vec<u16>` that preserve a *well-formed in UTF-16* invariant, namely that there is no unpaired surrogate.

But as you note in your question, JavaScript strings *can* contain unpaired surrogates. That’s because **JavaScript strings are not strictly UTF-16**, they really are arbitrary sequences of `u16` with no additional invariant.

With no invariant to maintain, I don’t think wrapper types are all that useful.

---

rust-encoding supports UTF-16-LE and UTF-16-BE based on bytes. You probably want UTF-16 based on `u16`’s instead.

`std::str::Utf16Units` is indeed not a string type. It is an iterator returned by the `str::utf16_units()` method that converts a Rust string to UTF-16 (not LE or BE). You can use `.collect()` on that iterator to get a `Vec<u16>` for example.

---

The only safe way to obtain `Rc<[u16]>` is to coerce from `Rc<[u16; N]>` whose size is known at compile-time, which is obviously impractical. I wouldn’t recommend the unsafe way: allocating memory, writing a header to it that hopefully matches the memory representation of `RcBox`, and transmuting.

If you’re gonna do it with raw memory allocation, better use your own type so that you can use its private fields. Tendril does this: https://github.com/servo/tendril/blob/master/src/buf32.rs

Or, if you’re willing to take the cost of the extra indirection, `Rc<Vec<u16>>` is safe and much easier.