# How to build an Rc<str> or Rc<[T]>?

Tags: rust

I'd like to create an `Rc<str>` because I want reduce the indirection from following the 2 pointers that accessing an `Rc<String>` requires. I need to use an `Rc` because I truly have shared ownership. I detail in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685345/is-there-a-rust-library-with-an-utf-16-string-type-intended-for-writing-a-java) more specific issues I have around my string type.

Rc [has a `?Sized` bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/rc/struct.Rc.html):

```
pub struct Rc<T: ?Sized> { /* fields omitted */ }
```

I've also heard that Rust 1.2 will come with proper support for storing unsized types in an `Rc`, but I'm unsure how this differs from 1.1.

Taking the `str` case as example, my [naive attempt](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fca759f20f7425dee5275bf9be3f4bf3&version=nightly) (also [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=05eb2b4ad1a61a888db02931c8e3c9ca&version=nightly) for building from a `String`) fails with:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let a: &str = "test";
    let b: Rc<str> = Rc::new(*a);
    println!("{}", b);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `str: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:5:22
  |
5 |     let b: Rc<str> = Rc::new(*a);
  |                      ^^^^^^^ `str` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `str`
  = note: required by `<std::rc::Rc<T>>::new`
```

It's clear that in order to create an `Rc<str>`, I need to copy the whole string: `RcBox` would be itself an unsized type, storing the string itself alongside the weak and strong pointers — the naive code above doesn't even make sense.

I've been told that one can not instantiate such type, but instead instantiate an `Rc<T>` with a sized `T` and then coerce it to an unsized type. The example given is for the storing a trait object: first create `Rc<ConcreteType>` and then coerce to `Rc<Trait>`. But this doesn't make sense either: neither [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8cedd3de4583d40d579520dba16b3106&version=nightly) nor [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=94408116502232ebdc77d43c24f5da5e&version=nightly) work (and you can't coerce from `&str` or `String` to `str` anyway).

Comment: Because accessing an `Rc<String>` requires following 2 pointers (also, I need `Rc` because I truly have shared ownership). I detail [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685345/is-there-a-rust-library-with-an-utf-16-string-type-intended-for-writing-a-java) more specific issues I've around my string type. My tentative definition `Rc<Utf16Str>` would also require an unsized type `Utf16Str` (it would have the same layout as `Rc<[u16]>`).

Comment: See also [Is it possible to create an Arc<[T\]> from a Vec<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44636833/155423).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As of Rust 1.21.0 and as mandated by [RFC 1845](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1845-shared-from-slice.md), creating an `Rc<str>` or `Arc<str>` is now possible:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::sync::Arc;

fn main() {
    let a: &str = "hello world";
    let b: Rc<str> = Rc::from(a);
    println!("{}", b);

    // or equivalently:
    let b: Rc<str> = a.into();
    println!("{}", b);

    // we can also do this for Arc,
    let a: &str = "hello world";
    let b: Arc<str> = Arc::from(a);
    println!("{}", b);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5d6c59178c780a43db54b20a349400c7&version=stable))

See [`<Rc as From<&str>>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#impl-From%3C%26%27a%20str%3E) and [`<Arc as From<&str>>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#impl-From%3C%26%27a%20str%3E).

Answer (score 10):

Creating an `Rc<[T]>` can be done via coercions and `as`-casts from fixed sized arrays, e.g. coercions can be done as follows:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let x: Rc<[i32; 4]> = Rc::new([1, 2, 3, 4]);

    let y: Rc<[i32]> = x;

    println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

However, this doesn't work for strings, since they have no raw fixed-sized equivalent to create the first value. It is possible to do unsafely, e.g. by creating a UTF-8 encoded `Rc<[u8]>` and transmuting that to `Rc<str>`. Theoretically there could be a crate on crates.io for it, but I can't find one at the moment.

An alternative is [`owning_ref`](https://crates.io/crates/owning_ref), which isn't quite `std::rc::Rc` itself, but should allow, for example, getting an `RcRef<..., str>` pointing into an `Rc<String>`. (This approach will work best if one uses `RcRef` uniformly in place of `Rc`, except for construction.)

```
extern crate owning_ref;
use owning_ref::RcRef;
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let some_string = "foo".to_owned();

    let val: RcRef<String> = RcRef::new(Rc::new(some_string));

    let borrowed: RcRef<String, str> = val.map(|s| &**s);

    let erased: RcRef<owning_ref::Erased, str> = borrowed.erase_owner();
}
```

The erasing means that `RcRef<..., str>`s can come from multiple different sources, e.g. a `RcRef<Erased, str>` can come from a string literal too.

NB. at the time of writing, the erasure with `RcRef` requires a nightly compiler, and depending on `owning_ref` with the `nightly` feature:

```
[dependencies]
owning_ref = { version = "0.1", features = ["nightly"] }
```

Comment: So a `Rc<[T]>` can't be created when the length of [T] is unknown at compile time, right? (But why is that? Isn't `Rc` allocated in the heap? since it's a fat pointer it already "knows" its size)

Comment: Yeah, an `Rc<[T]>` can't be constructed via coercion with dynamic lengths. However the concept totally makes sense, the only blocking problem is that there's no good way to construct one.

Comment: Also, would accessing the `String` inside `RcRef` require following two pointers? (the whole issue is that `Rc<String>` has a pointer to `String` that has a pointer to the beginning of the string...). I can't figure out if [this](https://github.com/Kimundi/owning-ref-rs/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L178) just has a pointer to the `String`.

Comment: Re: "the concept totally makes sense" - does it means that besides `Rc<[T]>`, `Rc<str>` (and other unsized types) *could* work on a future version of Rust?

Comment: @darque [it already can](http://is.gd/wWE4C6) for certain unsized types, like traits. This was new as of Rust 1.1 IIRC.

Comment: @darque, `Rc<str>` already does work: if you can make one (e.g. a `transmute` from UTF-8 `Rc<[u8]>` to `Rc<str>`) everything will work fine, there's just no safe way to construct one directly. The `RcRef` implementation does only require a single pointer access to read the `str` data.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a `Rc::clone_from(&T)` which would allow creating a `Rc<str>` from a `&str`?

Comment: @MatthieuM. @darque It should be possible to create a `Rc<[T]>` given a `&[T]` using a compiler-blessed standard library function. This would require unsafe code and rely on a certain memory layout. While the heap allocated block is expected to store two reference counters followed by the data, the core Rust language doesn't guarantee any memory layout for `#[repr(Rust)]` types so far. So, providing something like this as an external crate is kind of dangerous.