# Shared ownership of an str between a HashMap and a Vec

Tags: hashmap, rust

I come from a Java/C#/JavaScript background and I am trying to implement a `Dictionary` that would assign each passed string an id that never changes. The dictionary should be able to return a string by the specified id. This allows to store some data that has a lot of repetitive strings far more efficiently in the file system because only the ids of strings would be stored instead of entire strings.

I thought that a struct with a `HashMap` and a `Vec` would do but it turned out to be more complicated than that.

I started with the usage of `&str` as a key for `HashMap` and an item of `Vec` like in the following sample. The value of `HashMap` serves as an index into `Vec`.

```
pub struct Dictionary<'a> {
    values_map: HashMap<&'a str, u32>,
    keys_map: Vec<&'a str>
}

impl<'a> Dictionary<'a> {
    pub fn put_and_get_key(&mut self, value: &'a str) -> u32 {
        match self.values_map.get_mut(value) {
            None => {
                let id_usize = self.keys_map.len();
                let id = id_usize as u32;
                self.keys_map.push(value);
                self.values_map.insert(value, id);
                id
            },
            Some(&mut id) => id
        }
    }
}
```

This works just fine until it turns out that the `str`s need to be stored somewhere, preferably in this same `struct` as well. I tried to store a `Box<str>` in the `Vec` and `&'a str` in the `HashMap`.

```
pub struct Dictionary<'a> {
    values_map: HashMap<&'a str, u32>,
    keys_map: Vec<Box<str>>
}
```

The borrow checker did not allow this of course because it would have allowed a dangling pointer in the `HashMap` when an item is removed from the `Vec` (or in fact sometimes when another item is added to the `Vec` but this is an off-topic here).

I understood that I either need to write `unsafe` code or use some form of *shared ownership*, the simplest kind of which seems to be an `Rc`. The usage of `Rc<Box<str>>` looks like introducing double indirection but there seems to be no simple way to construct an `Rc<str>` at the moment.

```
pub struct Dictionary {
    values_map: HashMap<Rc<Box<str>>, u32>,
    keys_map: Vec<Rc<Box<str>>>
}

impl Dictionary {
    pub fn put_and_get_key(&mut self, value: &str) -> u32 {
        match self.values_map.get_mut(value) {
            None => {
                let id_usize = self.keys_map.len();
                let id = id_usize as u32;
                let value_to_store = Rc::new(value.to_owned().into_boxed_str());
                self.keys_map.push(value_to_store);
                self.values_map.insert(value_to_store, id);
                id
            },
            Some(&mut id) => id
        }
    }
}
```

Everything seems fine with regard to ownership semantics, but the code above does not compile because the `HashMap` now expects an `Rc`, not an `&str`:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::rc::Rc<Box<str>>: std::borrow::Borrow<str>` is not satisfied
  --> src/file_structure/sample_dictionary.rs:14:31
   |
14 |         match self.values_map.get_mut(value) {
   |                               ^^^^^^^ the trait `std::borrow::Borrow<str>` is not implemented for `std::rc::Rc<Box<str>>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
   = help:   <std::rc::Rc<T> as std::borrow::Borrow<T>>
```

Questions:

1. Is there a way to construct an `Rc<str>`?
2. Which other structures, methods or approaches could help to resolve this problem. Essentially, I need a way to efficiently store two maps `string-by-id` and `id-by-string` and be able to retrieve an id by `&str`, i.e. without any excessive allocations.

Comment: Related question on `Rc<str>`:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685697/how-to-build-an-rcstr-or-rct

Comment: I could believe that the [unsized coercions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0982-dst-coercion.md) might make it possible, at least on nightly, but I can't immediately see a way of doing so.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson: Like `owning_ref`, it could work pretty well in this situation.

Comment: [One question per question, please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to construct an `Rc<str>`?

Annoyingly, not that I know of. `Rc::new` requires a `Sized` argument, and I am not sure whether it is an actual limitation, or just something which was forgotten.

> Which other structures, methods or approaches could help to resolve this problem?

If you look at the signature of [`get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) you'll notice:

```
fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V>
    where K: Borrow<Q>, Q: Hash + Eq
```

As a result, you could search by `&str` if `K` implements `Borrow<str>`.

`String` implements `Borrow<str>`, so the simplest solution is to simply use `String` as a key. Sure it means you'll actually have two `String` instead of one... but it's simple. Certainly, a `String` is simpler to use than a `Box<str>` (although it uses 8 more bytes).

If you want to shave off this cost, you can use a custom structure instead:

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct RcStr(Rc<String>);
```

And then implement `Borrow<str>` for it. You'll then have 2 allocations per key (1 for `Rc` and 1 for `String`). Depending on the size of your `String`, it might consume less or more memory.

---

If you wish to got further (why not?), here are some ideas:

- implement your own reference-counted string, in a single heap-allocation,
- use a single arena for the slice inserted in the `Dictionary`,
- ...

Comment: Thank you so much, turns out I was just one step from the solution -- I tried to implement `Borrow<str>` for `Rc<Box<str>>` itself, which compiler didn't allow, so I only needed to wrap that `Rc` into my own `struct` and now it works! I don't want to use `String`s as keys due to unnecessary duplication of data as there probably going to be thousands of strings.

On the _go further_ note -- the second idea is very interesting, so perhaps I could implement one rather big string that would work as the storage for the whole `Dictionary`. I will probably look into that later, thank you!