# Is it possible to create an Arc<[T]> from a Vec<T>?

Tags: rust

To be more specific, why [doesn't](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.from_raw) `Arc<T>` implement `from_raw` with a dynamically sized `T` while `Box<T>` [does](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.from_raw)?

```
use std::sync::Arc;

fn main() {
    let x = vec![1, 2, 3].into_boxed_slice();
    let y = Box::into_raw(x);
    let z = unsafe { Arc::from_raw(y) }; // ERROR
}
```

([play](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fa45cfcf65c1af1d41c509b0aba66704&version=stable&backtrace=0))

As pointed out in the comments, `Arc::from_raw` *must* be used with a pointer from `Arc::into_raw`, so the above example doesn't make sense. My original question (Is it possible to create an `Arc<[T]>` from a `Vec<T>`) remains: is this possible, and if not, why?

Comment: Maybe that's a good thing: it would have been UB if that code compiled, because `Arc::from_raw` expects a pointer returned by `Arc::into_raw`. Nevertheless, the part where `from_raw` requires `T` to be sized might have a good answer.

Comment: Note that `Arc::from_raw()` must only be used with a value returned from `Arc::into_raw()` because `Arc` places a header before the data pointer, and `Arc::from_raw` expects to find that header by looking immediately before the pointer you provide.

Comment: See also [How to build an Rc<str> or Rc<[T\]>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31685697/155423).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of Rust 1.21.0, you can do this:

```
let thing: Arc<[i32]> = vec![1, 2, 3].into();
```

This was enabled by [RFC 1845](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1845-shared-from-slice.md):

> In addition: `From<Vec<T>> for Rc<[T]>` and `From<Box<T: ?Sized>> for Rc<T>` will be added.
>
> Identical APIs will also be added for `Arc`.

Internally, this [uses a method called `copy_from_slice`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.21.0/src/liballoc/arc.rs#L1391), so the allocation of the `Vec` is not reused. For the details why, check out [DK.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44641572/155423).

Answer (score 6):

No.

First of all, as already noted in comments, you can't toss raw pointers around willy-nilly like that.  To quote [the documentation of `Arc::from_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.from_raw):

> The raw pointer must have been previously returned by a call to a `Arc::into_raw`.

You absolutely **must** read the documentation any time you're using an `unsafe` method.

Secondly, the conversion you want is impossible.  `Vec<T>` → `Box<[T]>` works because, internally, `Vec<T>` is effectively a `(Box<[T]>, usize)` pair.  So, all the method does is give you access to that internal `Box<[T]>` pointer [1].  `Arc<[T]>`, however, is *not* physically compatible with a `Box<[T]>`, because it has to contain the reference counts.  The thing being pointed to by `Arc<T>` has a different size and layout to the thing being pointed to by `Box<T>`.

The only way you could get from `Vec<T>` to `Arc<[T]>` would be to reallocate the contents of the vector in a reference-counted allocation... which I'm not aware of any way to do.  I don't believe there's any particular reason it *couldn't* be implemented, it just hasn't [2].

All that said, I believe not being able to use dynamically sized types with `Arc::into_raw`/`Arc::from_raw` is a bug.  It's certainly possible to get `Arc`s with dynamically sized types... though only by casting from pointers to fixed-sized types.

---

[1]: Not quite.  `Vec<T>` doesn't *actually* have a `Box<[T]>` inside it, but it has something *compatible*.  It also has to shrink the slice to not contain uninitialised elements.

[2]: Rust does not, on the whole, have good support for allocating dynamically sized things in general.  It's possible that part of the reason for this hole in particular is that `Box<T>` *also* can't allocate arrays directly, which is possibly because `Vec<T>` exists, because `Vec<T>` used to be part of the language itself, and why would you add array allocation to `Box` when `Vec` already exists?  *"Why not have `ArcVec<T>`, then?"*  Because you'd never be able to *construct* one due to shared ownership.

Answer (score 3):

`Arc<[T]>` is an `Arc` containing a pointer to a slice of `T`'s. But `[T]` is not actually Sized at compile time since the compiler does not know how long it will be (versus &[T] which is just a reference and thus has a known size).

```
use std::sync::Arc;

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<u32> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let b: Box<[u32]> = v.into_boxed_slice();
    let y: Arc<[u32]> = Arc::new(*b);
    print!("{:?}", y)
}
```

[Play Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d134413b3278cdf8e5e16c66e1ee15c8&version=stable&backtrace=0)

However, you can make an `Arc<&[T]>` without making a boxed slice:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let y: Arc<&[u32]> = Arc::new(&v[..]);
    print!("{:?}", y)
}
```

[Shared Ref Play Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4278fb9d6b7e52d390d82e3eb2bbb3ad&version=stable&backtrace=0)

However, this seems like a study in the type system with little practical value. If what you really want is a view of the Vec that you can pass around between threads, an Arc<&[T]> will give you what you want. And if you need it to be on the heap, `Arc<Box<&[T]>>` works fine too.

Comment: You won't be able to pass `Arc<&[T]>` or `Arc<Box<&[T]>>` to another (unscoped) thread as they don't live for `'static`. Did you mean to write `Arc<[T]>` and `Arc<Box<[T]>>` respectively? In which case, the values in `Arc<[T]>` are already on the heap together with the counter, so the second allocation+indirection via `Box` is strictly superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

I built ArcVec for a project of mine:

```
use std::sync::{Arc,Mutex,MutexGuard};

#[derive(Debug,Clone)]
pub struct ArcVec<T> {
    v: Arc<Mutex<Vec<T>>>
}

impl<T> PartialEq for ArcVec<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        Arc::ptr_eq(&self.v, &other.v)
    }
}

impl<T> From<Vec<T>> for ArcVec<T> {
    fn from(value: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        Self { v: Arc::new(Mutex::new(value)) }
    }
}

impl<T> ArcVec<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {v: Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![]))}
    }
    pub fn get_vec(&self) -> MutexGuard<'_,Vec<T>> {
        self.v.lock().unwrap()
    }
    pub fn push( &self, v: T ) {
        self.get_vec().push(v)
    }
    pub fn insert( &self, index: usize, v: T ) {
        self.get_vec().insert(index, v)
    }
    pub fn remove( &self, index: usize) -> T {
        self.get_vec().remove( index )
    }
    pub fn append( &self, v: &mut Vec<T> ) {
        self.get_vec().append(v)
    }
    pub fn len( &self ) -> usize {
        self.get_vec().len()
    }
    pub fn clear( &self ) {
        self.get_vec().clear()
    }
    pub fn truncate( &self, len: usize ) {
        self.get_vec().truncate( len )
    }
    pub fn retain<F>(&self, f: F)
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        self.get_vec().retain( f )
    }
    pub fn retain_mut<F>(&self, f: F)
    where F: FnMut(&mut T) -> bool {
        self.get_vec().retain_mut( f )
    }
    pub fn position<F>( &self, f: F ) -> Option<usize>
    where F: FnMut( &T ) -> bool {
        self.get_vec().iter().position(f)
    }
    pub fn position_all<F>( &self, mut f: F ) -> Vec<usize>
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        let mut vec_res = vec![];
        let mut index: usize = 0;
        self.get_vec().iter().for_each(|x| {
            if (f)(x) {vec_res.push(index)};
            index += 1;
        } );
        vec_res
    }
    pub fn map<B,F>( &self, f: F ) -> Vec<B>
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> B {
        self.get_vec().iter().map(f).collect()
    }
    pub fn all<F>( &self, f: F ) -> bool
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        self.get_vec().iter().all(f)
    }
    pub fn any<F>( &self, f: F ) -> bool
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        self.get_vec().iter().any(f)
    }
    pub fn do_to<B,F>( &self, mut f: F, index: usize ) -> B
    where F: FnMut(&mut T) -> B {
        (f)( self.get_vec().get_mut(index).unwrap() )
    }
    pub fn for_each<F>( &self, f: F )
    where F: FnMut(&mut T) {
        self.get_vec().iter_mut().for_each(f)
    }
    pub fn substitute( &self, x: T, index: usize ) {
        if let Some(e) = self.get_vec().get_mut(index) {
            *e = x;
        }
    }
    pub fn substitute_where<F>( &self, x: T, mut f: F )
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        let mut mg = self.get_vec();
        for i in 0..mg.len() {
            let e = mg.get_mut(i).unwrap();
            if (f)(e) {
                *e = x;
                break
            }
        }
    }
    pub fn remove_where<F>( &self, mut f: F ) -> Option<T>
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        let mut mg = self.get_vec();
        for i in 0..mg.len() {
            if (f)(mg.get(i).unwrap()) {
                return Some(mg.remove(i))
            }
        }
        None
    }
    pub fn remove_where_all<F>( &self, mut f: F ) -> Vec<T>
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        let mut mg = self.get_vec();
        let mut v = vec![];
        let mut i = 0;
        while i < mg.len() {
            if (f)(mg.get(i).unwrap()) {
                v.push(mg.remove(i));
            } else {
                i += 1;
            }
        }
        v
    }
}

impl<T> ArcVec<T> 
where T: Clone {
    pub fn find_clone<F>(&self, f: F) -> Option<T>
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        if let Some(t) = self.position(f) {
            return Some(self.get_clone(t))
        }
        None
    }
    pub fn get_clone( &self, index: usize ) -> T {
        self.get_vec().get(index).unwrap().clone()
    }
    pub fn clone_all( &self ) -> Vec<T> {
        self.get_vec().clone()
    }
    pub fn clone_where<F>( &self, mut f: F ) -> Option<T>
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        let mg = self.get_vec();
        for i in 0..mg.len() {
            let e = mg.get(i).unwrap();
            if (f)(e) {
                return Some(e.clone())
            }
        }
        None
    }
    pub fn clone_where_all<F>( &self, mut f: F ) -> Vec<T>
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        let mg = self.get_vec();
        let mut res = vec![];
        for i in 0..mg.len() {
            let e = mg.get(i).unwrap();
            if (f)(e) {
                res.push(e.clone())
            }
        }
        res
    }
}
```

Async version:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::sync::{Mutex,MutexGuard};

#[derive(Debug,Clone)]
pub struct ArcVec<T> {
    v: Arc<Mutex<Vec<T>>>
}

impl<T> PartialEq for ArcVec<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        Arc::ptr_eq(&self.v, &other.v)
    }
}

impl<T> From<Vec<T>> for ArcVec<T> {
    fn from(value: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        Self { v: Arc::new(Mutex::new(value)) }
    }
}

impl<T> ArcVec<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {v: Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![]))}
    }
    pub async fn get_vec(&self) -> MutexGuard<'_,Vec<T>> {
        self.v.lock().await
    }
    pub async fn push( &self, v: T ) {
        self.get_vec().await.push(v)
    }
    pub async fn insert( &self, index: usize, v: T ) {
        self.get_vec().await.insert(index, v)
    }
    pub async fn remove( &self, index: usize) -> T {
        self.get_vec().await.remove( index )
    }
    pub async fn append( &self, v: &mut Vec<T> ) {
        self.get_vec().await.append(v)
    }
    pub async fn len( &self ) -> usize {
        self.get_vec().await.len()
    }
    pub async fn clear( &self ) {
        self.get_vec().await.clear()
    }
    pub async fn truncate( &self, len: usize ) {
        self.get_vec().await.truncate( len )
    }
    pub async fn retain<F>(&self, f: F)
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        self.get_vec().await.retain( f )
    }
    pub async fn retain_mut<F>(&self, f: F)
    where F: FnMut(&mut T) -> bool {
        self.get_vec().await.retain_mut( f )
    }
    pub async fn position<F>( &self, f: F ) -> Option<usize>
    where F: FnMut( &T ) -> bool {
        self.get_vec().await.iter().position(f)
    }
    pub async fn position_all<F>( &self, mut f: F ) -> Vec<usize>
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        let mut vec_res = vec![];
        let mut index: usize = 0;
        self.get_vec().await.iter().for_each(|x| {
            if (f)(x) {vec_res.push(index)};
            index += 1;
        } );
        vec_res
    }
    pub async fn map<B,F>( &self, f: F ) -> Vec<B>
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> B {
        self.get_vec().await.iter().map(f).collect()
    }
    pub async fn all<F>( &self, f: F ) -> bool
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        self.get_vec().await.iter().all(f)
    }
    pub async fn any<F>( &self, f: F ) -> bool
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        self.get_vec().await.iter().any(f)
    }
    pub async fn do_to<B,F>( &self, mut f: F, index: usize ) -> B
    where F: FnMut(&mut T) -> B {
        (f)( self.get_vec().await.get_mut(index).unwrap() )
    }
    pub async fn for_each<F>( &self, f: F )
    where F: FnMut(&mut T) {
        self.get_vec().await.iter_mut().for_each(f)
    }
    pub async fn substitute( &self, x: T, index: usize ) {
        if let Some(e) = self.get_vec().await.get_mut(index) {
            *e = x;
        }
    }
    pub async fn substitute_where<F>( &self, x: T, mut f: F )
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        let mut mg = self.get_vec().await;
        for i in 0..mg.len() {
            let e = mg.get_mut(i).unwrap();
            if (f)(e) {
                *e = x;
                break
            }
        }
    }
    pub async fn remove_where<F>( &self, mut f: F ) -> Option<T>
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        let mut mg = self.get_vec().await;
        for i in 0..mg.len() {
            if (f)(mg.get(i).unwrap()) {
                return Some(mg.remove(i))
            }
        }
        None
    }
    pub async fn remove_where_all<F>( &self, mut f: F ) -> Vec<T>
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        let mut mg = self.get_vec().await;
        let mut v = vec![];
        let mut i = 0;
        while i < mg.len() {
            if (f)(mg.get(i).unwrap()) {
                v.push(mg.remove(i));
            } else {
                i += 1;
            }
        }
        v
    }
}

impl<T> ArcVec<T> 
where T: Clone {
    pub async fn find_clone<F>(&self, f: F) -> Option<T>
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        if let Some(t) = self.position(f).await {
            return Some(self.get_clone(t).await)
        }
        None
    }
    pub async fn get_clone( &self, index: usize ) -> T {
        self.get_vec().await.get(index).unwrap().clone()
    }
    pub async fn clone_all( &self ) -> Vec<T> {
        self.get_vec().await.clone()
    }
    pub async fn clone_where<F>( &self, mut f: F ) -> Option<T>
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        let mg = self.get_vec().await;
        for i in 0..mg.len() {
            let e = mg.get(i).unwrap();
            if (f)(e) {
                return Some(e.clone())
            }
        }
        None
    }
    pub async fn clone_where_all<F>( &self, mut f: F ) -> Vec<T>
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
        let mg = self.get_vec().await;
        let mut res = vec![];
        for i in 0..mg.len() {
            let e = mg.get(i).unwrap();
            if (f)(e) {
                res.push(e.clone())
            }
        }
        res
    }
}
```