How can I avoid Rc<String> extra pointer indirection?
I'm writing a bit of code that uses Rc<String>. I'm pretty sure that using this would create an extra pointer indirection, with one pointer to the Rc, which has a pointer to String, which is a fat pointer to its actual contents.
Here is a diagram of what I think is happening (not exactly how rust makes the structs, just an approximation)
           -Rc-----------     -String------
my_var --> | ptr        | --> | ptr       | --> str
           | weak_ref   |     | length    |
           | strong_ref |     | capacity  |
           --------------     -------------

I came across this solution that used a Rc<str> to reduce the extra pointer indirection. But when I tried to use Rc::unwrap_or_clone(my_string) , the compiler gives a message about how my_string 's size cannot be know at compile time. But the string, in my use case, is constructed dynamically, and therefore the size can't possibly be known at compile time. I don't think using Rc<&str> works either, because it's a reference. Plus there needs to be a lifetime when it's put in a struct, which I really do not want to deal with.
I have also came cross a related thingy that makes a RcStr struct, but they are using a Rc<String> to store the underlying data, which doesn't avoid the extra pointer indirection.
What I am looking for is some way to somehow automatically merge the Rc and String structs together, something like this:
struct Merged {
    data: *mut u8,     // from string
    len: usize, 
    cap: usize,
    strong_ref: usize, // from rc
    weak_ref: usize,
}

Is this possible? or is there another solution to the extra indirection?

Unless you have &Rc<String>, you only have double indirection.

If you really need unwrap_or_clone(), then you cannot avoid Rc<String>; but do you really need it?

Assuming you have my_var: Rc<String>, then my_var IS the Rc, not some pointer/reference to it, hence double indirection.

Smart pointers often support unsized types. If you don't need to mutate the string, consider Rc<str>. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685697/how-to-build-an-rcstr-or-rct

What are you actually trying to do with this Rc<String>?

@ChayimFriedman thank you for bring that to my attention. I have edited my post to say extra instead of triple.

I have to agree that Rc<String> seems kind of pointless. You need interior mutability to use any functionality of String over str. So I think the reasonable ones are Rc<str> and Rc<RefCell<String>> or similar.

To aid in understanding the pointer indirections involved, I have some more accurate diagrams.
A my_var: Rc<String> holding "DATA" will have two indirections since it looks like this:
my_var:
-Rc------     -RcBox-----------
| ptr   | --> | weak_ref      |
---------     | strong_ref    |
              | -String------ |     -str-------
              | | ptr       | | --> | D A T A |
              | | length    | |     -----------
              | | capacity  | |
              | ------------- |
              -----------------

A my_var: Rc<str> holding "DATA" will have a single indirection and str being an unsized type makes the Rc handle "fat" and holds the additional length of the str:
my_var:
-Rc------     -RcBox---------
| ptr   | --> | weak_ref    |
| len   |     | strong_ref  |
---------     | -str------- |
              | | D A T A | |
              | ----------- |
              ---------------

You can hopefully see in the diagrams that it uses one less indirection than maybe you thought since the reference bookeeping and contents of the Rc are stored within the same allocation. Either that or variables themselves do not add a level of indirection themselves.
So Rc<str> is certainly more optimal in many respects, but since str is an unsized type you can't do some things common to sized types (like return it by value as unwrap_or_clone would do).

Thanks to the comments, I have refactored my code to not use the unwrap_or_clone() function. I opted to convert the Rc to a reference then called .to_string(). This works perfectly for my use case.
